# IntelliJ - rerunning part of a testcase

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, ide

Let's say I have a testcase

```
testSomething
    testA
    testB
    testC
    ...
```

If I run "testSomething", then "testA", "testB", ... are run in sequential order. Unfortunately, that's falsifying the statistics (time to run each individual test) due to caching.

If I select a single testcase, say, "testB" and re-run that one, I lose all information about the other tests as the result from the "testSomething"-run is thrown away and only "testB" is displayed.
Is there any way to prevent that from happening? I.e. keep everything displayed and just update the results for "testB"?

Comment: What framework do you use to execute those tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to update the results of a single test in a test tree. What you can do is pin the entire tab with the results of executing `testSomething` (right-click on the tab header and select "Pin tab" from the context menu) and then run `testB` again - then its results will be displayed in a separate tab and you'll still have access to the results of `testSomething`.